# php login script not displaying correctly

Tags: php, login-script

So i have created a user_login.php page (consisting of html, a login form), the form is :

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/login.php">

<p>Username: <input type="text" name="Username" /></p>

<p>Password: <input type="password" name="Password" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Sign In" /></p>

</form>
```

As well as this, I have a login.php script (see below)

```
<?php
   include "scripts/connection.php";
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer_Username = '$myusername' and Customer_Password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['Username'] = $myusername;

         header("location: Welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Username or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

Now i know my connection.php works, as I use it elsewhere on my site.

My problem is, when i browse the user_login.php page in my browser,when I click on the "sign in" button, it takes me to www.website.com/login.php file, but the entire page is blank (white).
This happens no matter if i input something into the username and password fields or leave them blank.

Obviously what i require is, if the fields are blank or dont match records within the DB, an error message is displayed. If the logins do match then they are redirected to the Welcome.php file.

Not 100% if the login.php script is missing anything so any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After adding :

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "scripts/connection.php";
```

to the top of my code, im getting a long error message now, instead of a pure white screen:

> Warning: include(scripts/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in scripts/login.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'scripts/connection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in scripts/login.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: link in scripts/login.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /scripts/login.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: link in /scripts/login.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /scripts/login.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: link in /scripts/login.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /scripts/login.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /scripts/login.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /scripts/login.php on line 18

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: What is your `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`? Have you echoed it out?

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry, when you ask what it is? What do you mean? Novice sorry....

Comment: What is the value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`? Add `echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];` prior to your `if` statement. My bet is that you never enter the `if` condition.

Comment: Start with the first error and many of the others will disappear.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im obviously missing something what is apparently clear to more experienced users sorry, you say the first error, which is failed to open stream, which you say is a duplicate. 
On line 5 in my login.php file it says include "script/connection.php";

When you suggest its a duplicate, do you mean to say i have included it when there is no need too ?

Comment: A duplicate here means the question has already been asked and answered, likely several times. The linked answer will generally have the information you need to fix you code and make things work properly.

Comment: see jay, literally exactly this reason why you don't just mark it a dupe in the middle of it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah okay, i noticed another commenter and yourself mentioned about the first error that is shown, misread what you were talking about, I will take a look at your answer now. Thanks

Comment: my first line should help you as well Tipping, have a look if you are still having trouble

Comment: @keaner , not sure if you saw my reply to your firstline answer, just incase: 

Yeah the connection and login.php are in the scripts folder, At the top of the login.php file I have included the connection.php script and nothing else, At the top of my user_login.php file i have included both the connection and login.php files (Tried deleting and adding only one at a time but same error message) hope im not being silly and missing something obvious?

Comment: If they are in the same folder do what @keaner said and change the line to `include "connection.php";`

Comment: @keaner #Okay finally understood what you meant by changing to "connection.php";
That has cleared all errors and redirects me to my welcome page on correct db entry!!! Thank you

Comment: Now that you have your code working @Tipping44 please pay attention to the first 2 comments left to you. Both of these are about safety and security of your code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard 
just added what you suggested and all that displays is POST

You may be rolling your eyes, trying to understand best i can sorry!

Comment: I was still trying to troubleshoot what was going on in your code once you had the connection problem fixed. You can ignore that now and pay attention to the comments left about security. In addition, as I have done, upvote @keaner's answer and then mark it as accepted when you are allowed to.

Comment: lol, this thread is gold, glad it all worked out for you, thx for the accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scripts/connection.php is in the same folder as your login.php then the include should only be

```
include "connection.php";
```

---

one thing, your `session_start();` needs to be the first line in your php, before including scripts. That is probably throwing an error (which you cant see), so the page is white blank.

Add this after the `session_start()`, then reload the page. So full code for the top should look like below

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "scripts/connection.php";
```

*UPDATE*

to trouble shoot id remove this part

```
if($count == 1) {
     $_SESSION['Username'] = $myusername;

     header("location: Welcome.php");
  }
```

and try this

```
if($count == 1) {
     echo "It WORKS";
  }
```

this will allow you to see if this condtion is being met, if so, the redirect is the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just added that in and the same thing occurs. No difference whatsoever :(
Sorry, just reloaded the page and i am now being shown a huge error starting with Warning: include(scripts/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/scripts/login.php on line 5 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'scripts/connection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') – Tipping44 4 mins ago    edit

Comment: take out session start completely to see if the page shows up, the fact that no error even showed is concerning, something in your php setup seems off, also post your new edited coded fully if you can

Comment: header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); should be first before any output. all this relates to php throwing errors you cant see (white page)

Comment: Do you mean for me to relocate this to the top of my page also? If so, as soon as i then click on my "user_login.php" page (as if a user is logging in) it redirects me to the "welcome.php" right away.

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look, to trouble shoot where its dying, try above. Yeah i meant edit your original question and provide all code as it sits now if you can, the header remark was to replace the header you had later on in the file, in the same spot, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for your input, just tried swapping out what you suggested and getting the same long error message. updated my original post with error message

Comment: what long error message? you said page was blank?

Comment: Righjt there, first comment to you @keaner *"Warning: include(scripts/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/scripts/login.php on line 5 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'scripts/connection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')"*

Comment: if your scripts/connection.php is in the same folder as your login.php then the include should only be  include "connection.php";

Comment: @keaner 

yeah the connection and login.php are in the scripts folder, 

At the top of the login.php file I have included the connection.php script and nothing else, 
At the top of my user_login.php file i have included both the connection and login.php files (Tried deleting and adding only one at a time but same error message) 

hope im not being silly and missing something obvious?

Comment: its only a "dupe" becuase we fixed his other problem, god forbid some other person might like to see the chain of events

Comment: Just because it is a dupe doesn't mean it will be deleted. As a matter of fact it will likely be kept around just so that people can see the chain of events @keaner. Nothing personal was meant be the dupe or the edit to your answer.